# changing a UITableView's frame in a UINavigationController after the view is loaded

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to change the frame size and position for two UITableViews that are inside a UIViewController that is the rootviewcontroller for UINavigationController.

I want the frame size to change upon a user action.  I have everything set up and the following code is executing upon the user's action:

```
CGRect firstTableFrame = [myTableView frame];
firstTableFrame.size.height = 290;  
[self.myTableView setFrame:firstTableFrame];
NSLog(@"%f",self.myTableView.frame.size.height);
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

I can confirm that the NSLog outputs 290. However, nothing on screen changes.  I found one answer on here that I thought might solve it (unchecking autolayout) for the .xib file but this results in all sorts of other layout issues with my .xib when I run it.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the navigation controller has a view which holds the view that you are adding into it (your table views). you have to resize that view too appropriately

Comment: I see.  So what would I do to that view?  Its' size doesn't need to change, just the size of the contents within its view (i.e. the tableviews).  I am assuming you mean I need to somehow let that view know I am changing it's subview or perhaps do it through that view. Any further advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Either you can take the rootController.view and set its bounds to be more than the size required by the two tableviews or just set it to the screen size of the device. You can also take the superview of the view of you viewcontroller and resize

Comment: I think I need to clarify that the table view that is getting resized is getting smaller.  It's height is going from 440 to 290.  Wouldn't the bounds of any super views in that case not need to be altered?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by going to the viewcontroller's .xib file and unchecking " use autolayout" in the File Inspector pane.  When that is unchecked, the constraints are removed and I was able to resize and reposition the frame programmatically.